# Java: Declaring a Map with two related generics Types (<T> Map<Class<? extends ClassA<T>>,Class<? extends ClassB<T>>>)

Tags: java, generics

Is it possible to declare a Map that maps from keys of a specific subclass to values of a specific subclass but ensuring that both classes share the same Type parameter?

For the background:

both ClassA and ClassB implement behaviour for a common resource

```
public abstract  class ClassA<T> {
      public abstract T getResource() ;
}

public abstract class classB<T> {
       public  abstract void consoumeResource(T resource);
}
```

i want to map from implementations of ClassA and ClassB and ensure only "compatible" pairs can be put together in one entry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way would be to provide your own `Map` implementation. There's not much code needed if you extend an existing implementation, and use your new type:

```
public class CompatibleHashMap<T> extends HashMap<ClassA<T>, ClassB<T>> {

}
```

Now, a `CompatibleHashMap<String>` only lets you put `ClassA<String>` as keys and `ClassB<String>` as values.

**EDIT:**

As you mentioned in your comment, this way you are tying yourself to a `Map` implementation. You can overcome this by doing something like the following:

```
public class CompatibleMap<T> implements Map<ClassA<T>, ClassB<T>> {

    private Map<ClassA<T>, ClassB<T>> map;

    public CompatibleMap(Map<ClassA<T>, ClassB<T>> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<List<T>> keySet() {
        return map.keySet();
    }
    // ... implement all other Map methods by calling the method on map.
}
```

You can then instantiate it like

```
CompatibleMap<String> map = new CompatibleMap<>(new HashMap<ClassA<String>, ClassB<String>>());
```

This way, you are not tied to a specific `Map` implementation, and the compiler will throw an error if the generic types of the `map`, `ClassA` and `ClassB` are not the same.

Comment: This isn't exactly what i was looking for, as I'm tying myself against a concrete Implementation of Map - but it's the best solution i can see. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this in the Map declaration but you can do this using methods which access/update the map.

e.g.

```
private final Map<Class, Builder> builderMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

public <T> void addBuilder(Class<T> tClass, Builder<T> tBuilder) {
     builderMap.put(tClass, tBuilder);
}

public <T> Builder<T> getBuilderFor(Class<T> tClass) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
    Builder<T> tBuilder = (Builder<T>) builderMap.get(tClass);
    return tBuilder;
}
```